# How to restrict rightBarButtonItem size in UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I create a rightBarButtonItem with this method :

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)customBarButtonWithSelector:(SEL)callback {
 UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 customButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30.0f, 30.0f);
 return [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton] autorelease];
}
```

At execution time the selector is fired when the bar is touched outside the button (near the middle).

Is there a way to restrict the event responder in the defined bounds or in a acceptable range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution at http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html
Really helpfull, don't forget to subclass UIToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a fixed space before the button in the array of bar button items.