# How to add round information button as a rightbarbuttonitem to navigation controller?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation controller. I want to add a right bar button item to that navigation controller. I am able to add one, but I want a specific style: labeled 'i' and also round in shape. Is there any property to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no property what you asked. But you can make a custom image and use this method.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:customImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(customButton:)];
addButton.enabled = YES;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

For more details you can refer [UIBarButtonItem ClassReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You can add your button 24 ways which are shown  UIBarButtonItem ClassReference. For round button, you can make custom image as round button.

Comment: how to fix the size of rightBarButtonItem of a navigationController?

Comment: I think [How to restrict rightBarButtonItem size in UINavigationBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712100/how-to-restrict-rightbarbuttonitem-size-in-uinavigationbar) will be helpful to you.

Comment: and also how to add a custom button to a UIBarButtonItem? I mean customizing UIBarButtonItem....